# Typescript interface type mapping to an object that consists of an original object and a new object built from original object's fields

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to map a type X to another type Y that consists of X and Z, where Z contains two values of X. Sounds convoluted, so you'll find the code below.

I have a following model for a data object from a database:

```
export interface Task {
 description: string;
 name: string;
 beginDate: string;
 endDate: string;
}
```

Having made a call to the DB, I would like to map these objects to the following type:

```
export interface TaskWithDate {
 task: Task;
 fullDate: FullDate;
}
```

where FullDate is an interface with the following definition:

```
export Interface FullDate {
 beginDate: string;
 endDate: string;
}
```

...and it should be filled with `beginDate` and `endDate` from a `Task`.

So, I make a call to the DB and want to do the mapping:

```
tasks: Task[];
this.tasks = this.getAllTasks(); // db call
this.ticketsWithDate = this.tasks.map(
      t => { return <TasktWithDate>{ task: t, fullDate: null }}
    );
```

**Question:**
How can I grab the `startDate`and `endDate` of `Task` (`t`) to create a `FullDate` object within the map function?

Comment: `t.startDate` and `t.endDate`?

Comment: Well, you can't do the following:  fullDate: t.beginDate, t.endDate

Comment: Culd you try using spread operator?

Comment: Sure but you want to make an object, right? So, make an oject and set the properties. `startDate: t.startDate`. It's *Exactly* the same as you already do with `task: t` - give the property name and its value. I don't see the problem here.

Comment: I'm not setting a property there, rather I want assign value to the data model described by the interface FullDate. I can't do fullDate: new FullDate(t.startDate, t.endDate) since it is not a class.

Comment: But you *can* do `fullDate: {startDate: t.startDate, endDate: t.endDate}`.

Comment: @Dawid but you *can* instantiate a plain object. Again ***exactly*** as you already do for `TasktWithDate` - by using `{}`.

Comment: why can't you just have fullDate: {beginDate: t.beginDate, endDate: t.endDate} ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate over the task array as you have done and then map the corresponding fields you need from it to form the `TaskWithDate` array as illustrated below:

```
ticketsWithDate: TaskWithDate[];

this.ticketsWithDate = this.tasks.map(
  tsk => {
    return {
      task: tsk,                       // map entire task object
      fullDate: {                      // fetch begin and end dates from task to 
        beginDate: tsk.beginDate,      // form a new key i.e fullDate
        endDate: tsk.endDate
      }
    };
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's simple , why don't you try just this,

```
this.ticketsWithDate = this.tasks.map(
    t => { 
        let fullDate: FullDate = {
            beginDate = t.beginDate,
            endDate = t.endDate
        }

        return <TasktWithDate>{ task: t, fullDate: fullDate }
    }
);
```

Or this,

```
this.ticketsWithDate = this.tasks.map(
t => { 
    return <TasktWithDate>{ task: t, fullDate: {
        beginDate = t.beginDate,
        endDate = t.endDate
    }
    }
}
```

);